# Fetching data from mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have a table structure like this:

```
bundle_id|service_id 

8|1

8|2

8|3

9|1

9|4

10|1

10|2

10|3

10|4

10|5
```

Now, I want to query the table to fetch the optimal bundle which has particular set of services.

E.g. If I want to fetch the bundle having services 1,2 and 3 then it should return 8 (and not 10).
Can anyone please help me with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT bundle_id 
FROM mappings
WHERE service_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY bundle_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT service_id) = 3
ORDER BY bundle_id LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT m.bundle_id  
FROM mappings m 
INNER JOIN (SELECT bundle_id, COUNT(DISTINCT service_id) serviceIdCnt 
            FROM mappings GROUP BY bundle_id
          ) A ON m.bundle_id = A.bundle_id 
WHERE m.service_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY m.bundle_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.service_id) = 3
ORDER BY A.serviceIdCnt LIMIT 1;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1018/5)

**OUTPUT**

```
| BUNDLE_ID |
|-----------|
|         8 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried the same query. the problem with this query is that, say, if table has one more entry with 9|5 then, bundle 9 will also be considered and will be picked up by the query as IN clause is evaluated as OR conditions.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Can you add `FIDDLE DEMO` to understand the issue which you are referring

Comment: @DarshanMehta Check the demo It is returning 8 only

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I added few rows in the table and now it is showing wrong bundle_id. Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1018/1

Comment: @DarshanMehta What is the logic behind selection of `bundle_id`?

Comment: It should exactly have those 3 services. If a bundle has more than 3 services (in our case) then the bundle with least number of extra services should be picked up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44852/discussion-between-darshan-mehta-and-saharsh-shah)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, it is working fine. Finally :)
I tried the following query and it seems I was very close. Missed by few inches.
`SELECT M.BUNDLE_ID, (SELECT COUNT(SERVICE_ID) FROM MAPPINGS WHERE BUNDLE_ID = M.BUNDLE_ID) AS COUNT 
FROM MAPPINGS M WHERE M.SERVICE_ID IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY BUNDLE_ID
HAVING COUNT = 3
ORDER BY COUNT LIMIT 0,1;`